# GraphicConverter 10.x - what is "image verification"? What does it do?

Tags: software, photo-viewer

I use GraphicConverter 10.x from AppStore. What is image verification? What does it do? Why does it needs so much CPU? I use MacBook Air.

[image]

Comment: Have you ask the support of manufacturer about those things?

Comment: Recommend closing as this is a software question, not photog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is described [by the manufacturer](https://prmac.com/release-id-67812.htm):

> Specifically added due to requests from users, this new feature is a background task that can regularly verify images on NAS devices.

I expect that what it does is run a hash function against all of the images stored on disk (or on NAS, or whatever), and record the hashes. A hash reduces a file of any size to a fixed-size number (like `d586818f7fcac69d460b5cb4bd3c4aced05f4010a037464928c0383e78d1e392`), and the important thing is that any small change in the data in the original file will result in a different hash. That means that this **protects against bitrot** -  if you run the verification again, and there is a change, you know that the file has changed, and if you didn't mean it to, you can pull down a clean version from your backups.

Hashing a file is both IO intensive (since the entirety of each file must be read) and CPU intensive (because, *math*), so it's completely expected for this to take a lot of computing power.